# How to access a Freestreamer Objective C class from Swift class?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am totally new to iOS development, and I decided to start directly with the new Swift programming language. But some Objective C knowledge is needed though, so this is a very basic question!

I am trying to use the [FreeStreamer library](https://github.com/muhku/FreeStreamer), to play a shoutcast stream in my iOS app. I followed the basic steps (copied among others the needed file in my Xcode project) but how can I access to the FSAudioStream from my Swift class?

I tried this:

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let test = FSAudioStream

    }
    // ...
}
```

But the `FSAudioStream` class is not found, which doesn't surprise me. Should I add an extra `import` to my file? In that case, which one?

Comment: I also tried to apply some of the advices provided on https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution from this [Apple Developer page on mixing Swift and Objective C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html).

But there was something important: when setting the "Objective-C Bridging header" in the "Swift Compiler - Code Generation" section of the project, the path has to be set **generally** which in turns set value for both the "Debug" and "Release" keys.

So I set the "Swift Compiler - Code Generation" parameter to `MyProject/MyProject-Header.h`.

And in the `MyProject/MyProject-Header.h` file I added this:

```
#import "FSAudioStream.h"
```

And then there is nothing to import in the Swift file.

Problem solved!